# Significance test to compare groups when a variable has multiple occurences per case

Tags: categorical-data, group-differences

I'm finishing a manuscript, but have one nagging problem which I'm unable to find an answer.

Study has two groups which receive different procedure for a disease. After the procedure, one patient may face multiple different adverse events (complications). I want to test if there is a difference in total number of adverse events between groups.

Obviously it would be all too easy with a simple single categorical variable, but I'm in doubt if using chi-squared or Fisher's test is the right approach. If I'm not mistaken, their presumptions differ.

One idea I got was to create a continuous dummy variable for total number of complications per case and compare those with t-test or something, but it still answers a bit different question imho.

The exact problem without reported answer can be found for example from the CHOCOLATE-trial (https://www.bmj.com/content/363/bmj.k3965.long) table 3, last 3 rows.

What is the correct approach?